# Tizen Linux is for Mobile & iPad - will this work with Ubuntu packages?

Tags: unity, package-management

I am compiling the Tizen Linux for Mobile and iPad. But inside Tizen can we deploy or use the repository from Ubuntu?

Because i have many application working under Ubuntu (but Ubuntu do not have mobile compatible hardwares or etc and also not have any iPad modules), how can we port ubuntu packages to Tizen?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i think you're asking two things here, How to port packages from Ubuntu to Tizen and will applications from Ubuntu work in Tizen?, I'd suggest you to read firstly the differences between Ubuntu and Tizen, just because they're Linux based doesn't mean that magically  they're compatible, I'd suggest you to also read about compatibility between Android and Ubuntu so you can have an idea about it, also Tizen up to this point was Meego and is said that it will be merged with Bada, I'd also suggest you to read the difference between x86 and ARM.